# angularjs draggable directive with containment and without jquery?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if there as a library or snippet available that anyone is aware of that will allow you to create a draggable div without using jquery and jquery ui?
I found this link

[angular draggable directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/RmzmgubOfF1VdU7HaAtp?p=preview)

```
<div my-draggable>content</div>
```

It works really well but there is no container functionality to restrict the drag so the user can only drag the image within a "container". Is there a way to accomplish this just using angular? Is there a library that does NOT have jquery as a dependency?

Comment: Any reason not to use the best tool available out there?

Comment: well I have seen alot of implementations for using jquery with it but I it adds and almost a 400kb of page-weight. the jquery, jquery-ui.js, jquery-ui-theme.css, jquery-ui-structure.css, jquery-ui.css and the images. I am trying to keep the pages lean. But if there is no other way I guess that I would have use it.